# How can the design of a Branch "Link Domain" page be edited?

Tags: app-store, branch, branch.io, applinks

How do I edit the design (html, img, css) of the page hosted at [myapp].app.link? I have configured this in my Branch account configuration as the "Link Domain" for my app redirect.

This Branch.io help page seems to imply that the page is customizable: https://branch.io/what-is-applink/

Answer (score 0):

As per Branch support: The page being referred to is called a Deepview. A Deepview is a mobile web splash page, hosted by Branch, that gives a preview of the in-app content behind a given Branch link.

For more information on the same, you can go through the documentation below:

https://help.branch.io/using-branch/docs/deepviews#overview

You can navigate to your Deepview setting from the Configuration page and then navigate to the Deepviews tab. You can not edit the existing Deepviews, however, you can create your own custom Deepview. Do go through the following documentation for a step by step guide:

https://help.branch.io/using-branch/docs/deepviews#1-enable-default-deepviews-templates

https://help.branch.io/using-branch/docs/deepviews#1a-create-a-custom-deepview-template